# DNS CNAME record to maintain the same URL and point to another site hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, amazon-route53, cname

I have been working on a React js site that will be an exctension of my companies WooCommerce site, the react site is being hosted and managed on AWS Amplify and the WooComerce site is hosted with WP-Engine.

I would need the site to maintain the same domain URl as:

[www.ourdomain.com/my-library](http://www.ourdomain.com/my-library) to point to my react app hosted on Amplify but to keep the url as [www.ourdomain.com/my-library](http://www.ourdomain.com/my-library) so it looks like they are still on the same site.

I think I can create a CNAME record using route 53? Could any one help me on this one please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one CNAME record for `www.ourdomain.com`, and it sounds like you currently have one that is pointing to your WooCommerce site. You can't add another one with the same name pointing somewhere else. And if you aren't already using Route53 as your authoritative DNS sever, then you can't use Route53 for this at all anyway.

What you need to do is setup a proxy in front of both websites, that sends traffic to the different backends (WooComerce or Amplify) depending on the request's path, and change your current CNAME record to point to that proxy. The AWS service that you would use to accomplish this is [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thank you for your Answer Mark. OK that makes sense. So I would have to have ourdomain.com point to route53, and route53 would then point to our wooComerce, and if it wass ourdomain.com/my-library it would point to my amplify...

Would I have to configure all other paths as well? 

Obviously the WooComerce site has it's own paths  and the Amplify app has it's own.

Comment: Take your comment and replace "Route53" with "CloudFront", and that is what I said you would need to do. I did not say you should use Route53. You would have a default origin that CloudFront sends all your requests to. And then you would have a path mapping for `/my-library` that sends those requests to Ampllify instead.

Comment: Yes Sorry I meant to say CloudFront. Sorry still get confused with so many services. Thank you Mark Appreciate you replies.